# What is the meaning of "StandardProductID" (ASIN) in Amazon Seller inventory?

Tags: xml, salesforce, integration, amazonsellercentral

We are trying to create products in Amazon seller account via feed api using xml files . I saw there is a tag for "StandardProductID" in xml but I want to know that should we create this id for amazon or amazon will create these ids after successful product feed operation .
NOTE : We are sending products from salesforce to Amazon seller account.
Basic question :

- What is the exact use of StandardProductID ID (ASIN) .
- How to create this ID if we have to add this in xml while creating product for first time.
  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The StandardProductTypeID specifies either an ASIN, UPC or EAN number. You should use the ASIN if you have it, otherwise the UPC or EAN. For example:

```
  <StandardProductID>
    <Type>ASIN</Type>
    <Value>B000LQLG7E</Value>
  </StandardProductID>
```

or, if you don't have the ASIN:

```
  <StandardProductID>
    <Type>UPC</Type>
    <Value>722470314639</Value>
  </StandardProductID>
```

Comment: You can also specify 'GTIN' for GTIN values.

Comment: According to our Amazon reps, they've made recent changes now where it's better to send the UPC if you have it, rather than the ASIN.