# What is the meaning of “StandardProductID” (ASIN and EAN)

Tags: amazonsellercentral

I have that answer here "[What is the meaning of "StandardProductID" (ASIN) in Amazon Seller inventory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860007/what-is-the-meaning-of-standardproductid-asin-in-amazon-seller-inventory)" but I want to know how to use them together (EAN and ASIN)?

```
<StandardProductID>
  <Type>ASIN</Type>
  <Value>B000LQLG7E</Value>
</StandardProductID>

<StandardProductID>
  <Type>EAN</Type>
  <Value>9006900212131</Value>
</StandardProductID>
```

This is an example for ASIN and for EAN.

Thanks!

Comment: Please indicate EAN as well

Comment: Ok, now you have examples of EAN and ASIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon has different product identifiers according to different international standards. You usually should not try to use both of them together as you're asking, instead the normal procedure is to use one of them and Amazon should be able to get the rest.

As the answer you linked says: Uou should use the ASIN if you have it, otherwise one of the other standards.

To know what each of those mean, have a look at this answer in Amazon help: [What are UPCs, EANs, ISBNs and ASINs?](https://www.amazon.com/gp/seller/asin-upc-isbn-info.html)

> What are UPCs, EANs, ISBNs. and ASINs?
>
> UPC Universal Product Code (UPC) is a 12-digit bar code used
>   extensively for retail packaging in United States.
>
> EAN The European Article Number (EAN) is a barcode standard, a 12- or
>   13-digit product identification  code. Each EAN uniquely identifies
>   the product, manufacturer, and its attributes; typically, the EAN is
>   printed on a product label or packaging as a bar code. We require EAN
>   codes to improve quality of search results and the quality of the
>   catalog as a whole. You can obtain EANs from the manufacturer. If your
>   products do not have manufacturer EANs, and you need to buy EAN codes,
>   you; should go directly to GS1 UK http://www.gs1uk.org
>
> For example, the EAN of  "Colgate Total 75 ml" is 4011200296908
>
> ISBN The International Standard Book Number (ISBN) is a unique
>   commercial book identifier barcode. Each ISBN code identifies uniquely
>   a book. ISBN have either 10 or 13 digits. All ISBN assigned after 1
>   Jan 2007 have 13 digits. Typically, the ISBN is printed on the back
>   cover of the book.
>
> For example, the ISBN code for J.K.Rowling's "Harry Potter and the
>   Deathly Hallows", Adult Edition, Paperback, UK edition is
>   978-0747595823, and this code identifies uniquely this book and
>   edition.
>
> ASINs
>
> Amazon Standard Identification Numbers (ASINs) are unique blocks of 10
>   letters and/or numbers that identify items. You can find the ASIN on
>   the item's product information page at Amazon.com. For books, the ASIN
>   is the same as the ISBN number, but for all other products a new ASIN
>   is created when the item is uploaded to our catalogue. You will find
>   an item's ASIN on the product detail page alongside further details
>   relating to the item, which may include information such as size,
>   number of pages (if it's a book) or number of discs (if it's a CD).
>
> ASINs can be used to search for items in our catalogue. If you know
>   the ASIN or ISBN of the item you are looking for, simply type it into
>   the search box (which can be found near the top of most pages), hit
>   the "Go" button and, if the item is listed in our catalogue, it will
>   appear in your search results.
>
> For example, the ASIN for Hasbro's "Monopoly" game is B00005N5PF.

For more information you can read about each standard separately:

- [UPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code)
- [EAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number) (now renamed to IAN - "european" changed for "international")
- [ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)
- [ASIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number)

Comment: Thank you! It's helped me a lot.